# counter example for Hasse Norm theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I was looking for examples for which Hasse-Norm theorem fails for abelian extensions. I found one which is given by $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt{17})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. The solution I saw shows $-1$ is a not global norm but is a local norm everywhere.

They've used in their argument that $L_{P}/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is unramified extension for all primes $p\neq 17,13$ and for all prime ideals $P$ lying over $p$. Could anyone prove this statement ? I don't really understand how to do it.

Comment: Well, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{13})$ is ramified only at $13$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{17})$ is ramified only at $17$. So the only ramification of the compositum is at the intersection of the two sets of unramified places. (Compositum of two unramifieds is unramified.)

Comment: How I don't understand. Could you please elaborate ?  I mean you're dealing with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt{17})$ but here I want $\mathbb{Q}_P(\sqrt{13},\sqrt{17})$

Comment: Well, if $(p)$ factors as a product of primes $P_i$ (with exponent $1$) in the integers of $K$, then the number $p$ is a uniformizer in each complete field $K_{P_i}$. I guess that’s how you connect global unramifiedness to the local concept.